# How to find software or drivers for an unknown RGB keyboard?

Tags: drivers, keyboard

Got my keyboard when I bought my computer, the RGB turns on for each key when pressed but I want to customize it. Surprisingly enough there is no sticker with any company name on the keyboard so I do not know what keyboard software to use. Device manager just said my keyboard is an HID, so doesn't say much.

Comment: HID is Human Interface Device, but you should see a device ID which will give you the manufacturer

Comment: If the keyboard is unbranded then there might as well be a big chance that the RGB isn't customizable to begin with. A large amount of cheap RGB keyboards are hardwired and don't really provide a way to customize their light presets.

Answer (score 2):

You need find the device exact model to check if a driver is required for it.

- Start Device Manager
- Open the Human Interface Devices section
- If a keyboard is listed, you have found it and Windows already has identified it as a keyboard.

  - Right-click the keyboard and select Properties
  - Go to the Details tab
  - Report to us the values you see for the two drop-down entries of
    "Device description" and of "Hardware IDs".
  - Stop here
- Otherwise, open the Keyboards section
- Right-click the first HID Keyboard Device
- Report to us the value for the drop-down entry of Hardware IDs.

Once you have the Hardware ID of the keyboard, it will have a format similar
to `VEN_10EC&DEV_8168`, which means vendor ID is `10EC` and device ID is `8168`.

Find the device in the
[PCI database lookup](https://www.oueta.com/pci-database/)
and enter the vendor ID and device ID in their fields:

[image]

Comment: HID\VID_258A&PID_001A&REV_3090&MI_01&Col05 is the first value when I selected Hardware ID for keyboards. Assumed that the VID is the vendor ID, so 258A, and then idk what device ID would be. I tried to use 001A and 3090 as the Device ID but the site said no hardware was found

Comment: In your case the mouse is apparently not the first entry. Please add here the others.

Comment: I'm not sure this works for keyboards, my Cherry keyboard comes up as "Unknown". Nice site though, I've added it to my resources list.

Comment: I have a generic Chinese keyboard branded under name of some local store. It have the same Vendor ID 258A. And yes, I looking is there is a software for it or not (nothing was mentioned about it in keyboard instruction, but you never know with those cheap Chinese products.

Answer (score 0):

I found software that works with my own unbranded keyboard that has a similar Vendor ID as yours (HID\VID_258A&PID_0016&REV_0001&MI_00
). It was software for A-Jazz AK525

Since you have the same vendor id you probably should check other their drivers

http://www.a-jazz.com/h-col-101.html (yes, you need to use Chinese version of the site)